# Get all domains for a tenant through REST API

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office365, azure-active-directory, onedrive

I want to know if there is a way to retrieve the registered domain(s) for a tenant through REST API for Sharepoint/Office365.

Consider this scenario;

I have a tenant named **abc.pqr** and url for the "my" site(OneDrive) is **abc-my.sharepoint.com**.

Now when I create a user for this tenant, the UI panel gives the option to select a domain for this account. Available options are;

```
1) @abc.pqr
2) @abc.onmicrosoft.com
```

Now, the problem is, if I have a user of this sort >>> **testUser@abc.onmicrosoft.com**, how do I findout the registered domain for this tenant? Which in my case is **abc.pqr**.

Is there a way to find this through REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like what you want to know is the list of verified domains in your Azure Active Directory tenant. (Azure AD is the directory service behind Office 365 and other Microsoft online services.)

The [Azure AD Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx)—AAD's REST API—can provide this for you. In your case, the GET request you would want to make is:

```
https://graph.windows.net/abc.onmicrosoft.com/tenantDetails
```

Note: you can use either the tenant ID or any verified domain of the tenant instead of `abc.onmicrosoft.com`. The tenant ID can be obtained from the `tid` claim in the access token.

The JSON response will include something like this:

```js
  "verifiedDomains": [
    {
      "capabilities": "None",
      "default": true,
      "id": "0007ABE0983098",
      "initial": false,
      "name": "abc.pqr",
      "type": "Managed"
    },
    {
      "capabilities": "Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline",
      "default": false,
      "id": "0007ABE0983098",
      "initial": true,
      "name": "abc.onmicrosoft.com",
      "type": "Managed"
    }
  ]
```

(There's a useful [Quickstart for the Azure AD Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835136.aspx) that shows how to start playing around with AAD Graph API, and the [GraphExplorer](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net).)

If you're using .NET, there is a full sample at https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-DotNet. (More samples for other languages and platforms at https://github.com/AzureADSamples.)

Comment: Thanks alot! Is there any way I could get this information without adding "abc.onmicrosft.com" to the URL. I have the access token for Graph API and I was hoping that would be enough to verify the tenant (I am referring to the /common URL that is supported for diff Graph API calls, instead of providing tenant name in the URL)
I'm looking for something like >>> https://graph.windows.net/common/tenantDetails?api-version=2013-04-05
... Is this possible?

Comment: Just tried this >>> https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/tenantDetails?api-version=2013-04-05 ... no luck!

Comment: You will need to have either a verified domain of the tenant (any verified domain works) or the tenant ID. The tenant ID is provided in the access token (`tid`), as is the authenticated user's UserPrincipalName (`upn`, from which you can get the domain name).

Comment: Two things: 1) you need a full domain name (just the part before ".onmicrosoft.com" won't work) or tenant ID, and 2) doesn't matter in this case, but you should really use a newer version (`1.5` is the latest).